# published a package(vue-izitheme) in npm. It works in command line, but it's not shown in serach. any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, plugins, themes

I published vue-izitheme, 2 days ago but it still doesn't come up when I search for it.

It works fine with the command line(also has been downloaded 44 times).

any ideas what the problem might be?

here's the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-izitheme

Comment: Contact [support](https://www.npmjs.com/support?inquire=account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted support and according to what they said, npmjs website had a bug which they fixed.